# Nested For Loop In Terminal

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a directory with 31 different files, each representing a CELL_TYPE (a sample of these are shown below).

```
topControlGenes.GeneSet                          
topProjection_Cluster5Genes.GeneSet
topAstrocytesGenes.GeneSet                       
topProjection_Cluster6Genes.GeneSet
topNeuronsInhCGE1Genes.GeneSet  
topNeuronsInhCGE2Genes.GeneSet
```

I have a script that generates 22 new files for each CELL_TYPE file (so 31 * 22 = 682 files).

```
for i in `seq 1 22`; do python make_annot.py --gene-set-file CELL_TYPEGenes.GeneSet  --bimfile ../../1000G_EUR_Phase3_plink/1000G.EUR.QC.${i}.bim --annot-file CELL_TYPE.${i}.annot.gz;done
```

This works well for each file, but I do not want to change the name in the command each time the script finishes. Instead, I want to run this command for every file in my directory.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what are your expected output for each input?

Comment: A set of 22 files named CELL_TYPE.chr#.annot.gz where CELL_TYPE is for each cell in the directory, and chr# is a number from 1 - 22.

Comment: Does `make_annot.py` have something like help flag (`-h/--help`)? If it does, it would be nice of you to post the help page here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using a nested for loop:

```
# Iterate over all GeneSet files
for f in *.GeneSet; do
    # Figure out the cell type by removing "Genes.GeneSet" from the end of the filename
    cell_type=${f%Genes.GeneSet}
    # Process the file
    echo "Processing file: $f with cell type $cell_type"
    for i in {1..22}; do
        python make_annot.py --gene-set-file "$f"  --bimfile ../../1000G_EUR_Phase3_plink/1000G.EUR.QC.${i}.bim --annot-file ${cell_type}.${i}.annot.gz
    done
done
```

Comment: This worked well. Thank you for your clear answer, now I know how to write nested loops in bash!

Comment: The inner for loop can be written more efficiently as `for ((i=1; i <= 22; i++)); do` so that we eliminate the external command `seq`.

Comment: Is using that method measurably faster for you (or do you have a source on it being faster)? 

It seems reasonable that it would be (since it doesn't need external commands) but in my testing using seq (`time for i in `seq 1 100000`; do :; done`) is about as fast as using brace expansion (`time for i in {1..100000}; do :; done`), whereas using loop checks (`time for ((i=1; i <= 100000; i++)); do :; done`) takes twice as long (testing on both macOS and linux).

I've changed the answer to use brace expansion for now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following nested `for` loops:

```
for f in *Genes.GeneSet 
do 
    for i in `seq 1 22`
    do 
        python make_annot.py --gene-set-file "${f}"  --bimfile ../../1000G_EUR_Phase3_plink/1000G.EUR.QC.${i}.bim --annot-file `echo "${f}" | grep -oP '^.*(?=Genes.Geneset$)'`.${i}.annot.gz; 
    done
done
```

This will loop on all your `CELL_TYPEGenes.GeneSet` and your `CELL_TYPE.${i}.annot.gz` to generate your `31 * 22 = 682 files` combinations

Where `echo "${f}" | grep -oP '^.*(?=Genes.Geneset$)'` is used to get the CELL_TYPE part of the filename

Comment: @erip: Edited, as it is actually totally unnecessary  ;-) Thanks for your feedback!